# Computing integral with floor function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

**Question**

Find the exact value of $$\int_{1}^{2016}\frac {\lfloor \ln x \rfloor} {x}\ \mathrm{d}x\ .$$

**My working**

My intuition is to treat the integral without the floor function and integrate, then "put back" the floor function after, so $$\int_{1}^{2016}\frac {\lfloor \ln x \rfloor} {x}\ \mathrm{d}x = \frac 1 2 [(\lfloor \ln x \rfloor)^2]^{x = 2016}_{x = 1}\ .$$

---

May I know if my intuition is correct? If not, what would be the right way to do this? This is my first time encountering an integral with the floor function. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Well, one thing which strikes me at first for solving this would be as follows. ln1=0, ln2016 = 7.6 (approx). there would be points along the x axis where the floor function is discontinuous. Break your integral about those points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is a plot of floor(ln(x)) along x axis.Find these points of discontinuity and break your integral at these points. The the numerator in all of these sub parts will be a constant and you will have just $\frac{some-constant}{x}$ as the integrand.

You can find these points of discontinuity using desmos.com or a scientific calculator (which is easily available on smartphones or computers these days).

Comment: The key takeaway here is that there is no direct method for integrating curves which are discontinuous (like floor, ceil, piece-wise defined). Integration is done simply by applying the concept that integration in 2d curves is just the area under the defined curves.

Comment: I had the same idea but he wants the exact value. How do you compute the exact values of the discontinuities ?

Comment: Thank you! I believe I have solved it :)

Comment: How did you find the exact values of the discontinuities ? @EthanMark

Comment: @nicomezi Hi, sorry for the really late reply. I missed this and happened to stumble upon it while reviewing my older questions. Not sure if you still need it, but it really boils down to some guess-and-check work.

Comment: I do not need it but I am curious. I am still not sure you can find an exact value, but yes you can probably estimate the integral value as closer as you want. (And thank you for the reply ;) ) @EthanMark

Comment: @nicomezi $\int^{2016}_1 \frac {\lfloor \ln x \rfloor} {x}\ \mathrm{d}x = \int^{e^1}_{e^0} \frac 0 x\ \mathrm{d}x + \int^{e^2}_{e^1} \frac 1 x\ \mathrm{d}x + \ldots + \int^{e^7}_{e^6} \frac 6 x\ \mathrm{d}x + \int^{2016}_{e^7} \frac 7 x\ \mathrm{d}x$. The "pattern" can actually be generalised to any integral involving a floor function. I hope this satisfies your curiosity!

Comment: It does ! Did not think about that. Thank you. @EthanMark

Comment: @nicomezi No problem!